# make won't build but g++ compiles fine

Tags: makefile, g++, mingw

I have a program which includes some SDL headers, but since I reinstalled windows make does not work anymore. It says that the include headers are not found. Running g++ with the exact output of make works fine.

I am running windows 10 with mingw to play around with some c++. I've written a small mcve to illustrate my problem. If I build with make this happens:

```
D:\TESTING\test>mingw32-make all
g++ *pp -ID:\LIBS\testlib -o test.exe
test.cpp:1:10: fatal error: t.h: No such file or directory
#include <t.h>
      ^~~~~
compilation terminated.
Makefile:6: recipe for target 'all' failed
mingw32-make: *** [all] Error 1
```

But if I run the output of make directly:

```
 g++ *pp -ID:\LIBS\testlib -o test.exe
```

The program compiles fine.

Here is the cpp code:

```
#include <t.h>
int main(int argc, char * args[]) {
std::cout << t <<std::endl;
}
```

The header file (in D:\LIBS\testlib):

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
std::string t = "meh";
```

And the Makefile:

```
CC=g++
OBJS = *pp
INCLUDE_PATHS = -ID:\LIBS\testlib
OBJ_NAME = test.exe
all : $(OBJS)
    $(CC) $(OBJS) $(INCLUDE_PATHS) -o $(OBJ_NAME)
```

Comment: When make runs is gcc running in a unix regime? Paths then use forward slashes not backlslashes, eg `-ID:\LIBS\testlib` will work from the windows cmd prompt but not from the unix-like shell that make launches? try with forward slashes.

Comment: @lurker Yes, changed it in the op

Comment: Following up on @GemTaylor comment, inside the makefile, try `-I/d/LIBS/testlib`.

Comment: @GemTaylor Thats it, works flawlessly now. I really wonder why the same makefile built with no issues on my old system. It was also mingw32.

Comment: Are you sure you weren't using a windows make before, like nmake? Then gcc would be called in windows path mode.

Comment: @GemTaylor Yes, still using the same tasks.json in VScode (command: "mingw32-make all")

Comment: Because backslash is a special symbol in many systems, including `make`. It shouldn't be in GNU Make, but apparently Microsoft's `nmake` is first on your `PATH`.